# Directly referencing userform entry in VBA instead of passing value to a variable

Tags: vba, excel

folks.  I am new to programming, but I am writing some macros to help manage a shared Excel workbook for my job.

I am implementing a few different user roles for people who need to access this workbook. The security is not very critical, just to prevent people from accidentally making (and saving) changes to things they shouldn't be. I am just having a UserForm prompt for the password and, based on what's entered, grant the proper access.

I have it written so that the user's entry into textbox on the UserForm is referenced directly as `Me.textboxPasswordEntry.Value` for any comparisons. It occurs to me that this may not be best practice, but I can't put my finger on why. Maybe I'm just over thinking? At the same time, it seems silly and wasteful to declare a variable, pass the value to the variable, and then analyze that.

The Sub below is from the UserForm, and I've included it to show you what I mean.  This is a very straight-forward scenario, I know, but am I courting trouble if I continue this practice through more complex ones?  If so, what kind of problems might I run into?

Thanks.

```
Private Sub buttonOK_adminPW_Click()
'The subs SetUserType_[level] are in the ChangeUserType module
'AdminPass and DesignPass are module-level variables set on UserForm initialization
'Default user type is User. Read-only access.
'Admins can edit the workbook, but must save via a macro to ensure
'   things are reset properly for Users (some sheets hidden, etc.)
'Designers can edit the workbook, but also have full ability to save using
'   the regular file menu/ctrl+s/etc.

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Select Case Me.textboxPasswordEntry.Value
        Case AdminPass
            'Shows right control buttons and unlocks the wkbk for admin access
            SetUserType_admin
            Unload Me
        Case DesignPass
            'Shows all control buttons and unlocks the wkbk for designer access
            SetUserType_design
            Unload Me
        Case Else
            MsgBox ("Password incorrect. Please retry.")
            With Me.textboxPasswordEntry
                .Value = ""
                .SetFocus
            End With
    End Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Generally speaking, use variables to represent objects/values which are referenced multiple times within the procedure. In this case, I wouldn't bother by changing it to a variable.  When a variable is used many times in a procedure, it's often easier to change the assignment, than it is to locate and change every single reference to it. For example, if someone changes the design of your UI and renames the control `password_tbox`, you would only need to change it in one place.

Comment: @DavidZemens, I was looking back over this question and only just realized I forgot to thank you for your reply.  My thinking is the same as yours, so it's reassuring as a novice to get that confirmed and quiet that nagging doubt (a bit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah I've also pondered over "best practise" with userforms over the years... I guess it's just through experience that I use approach below most often:

1. Use as little code as possible in the userform itself (thinking
   is, the form is more "reusable" if it does as little as possible
   back to its parent... its reason for existance is just to get input)
2. Do use code on the "activate" event of the form to clear all the
   fields on the form (this makes sense to be in the form because then
   you don't need to remember every control on the form to clear at
   every point you use it)
3. Either directly reference objects from
   the form in your calling code (i.e. stPassword =
   userform1.tbPassword.value) or...
4. Use "public" variables in the
   userform ... i.e. before all code in userform declare "public stPasswordInput as string" then you can reference in your calling code with e.g. stPassword = userform1.stPasswordInput

I'm keen to see what other people suggest though!

Comment: Hi, Simon.  Thank you for the reply!  These are definitely useful tips.  I've had to step away from the project for the last month, but a little distance has made looking back at my work so far...um...cringe-worthy.  I am planning to totally overhaul what I've done so far and will be using these four points.